# I can't seem to install django framework with pip on python 3.5.1, keep getting this error

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pip

[image]

What can i do to fix the issue?

Comment: try running cmd as administrator

Comment: works now... thanks alot

Comment: Instead of posting a hard to read screenshot, you should post the *actual* text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a permission denied error. This means that you do not have the required privileges to perform the operation. Run the command prompt as administrator so that you will not get this error.